# Can't find Python environment file in pycharm after creating it in the terminal of POP!_os (which is similar to ubuntu)

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I created the environment using conda:

```
conda create -n tensorEnv-gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'm still very new to python and Linux, so you'll probably have to be patient when explaining some commands or actions lol.

[image: Image of path where environment is stored.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `/home/trkornman/anaconda3/envs/tensorEnv-gpu/bin/` and select the file called `python`. That should do it.

Comment: thank you! I was confused because in a tutorial it showed in the tensorEnv-gpu folder.

Comment: Actually this always happens, anytime you create a virtual environment called `any_name_you_put_on_it` inside there's going to be a `bin` folder and a `python` file (link, shortcut) inside of this.